# TypeScript Reflection on type?

Tags: typescript, types, reflection

I have a `TypeScript` `type` defined by:

```
export enum eNum {
    FOO = 0,
    BAR = 1
}
export type foo = {
    bar: string,
    baz?: number,
    qux?: eNum
};
```

And would like to be able to attain reflection data into something like:

```
{
    name: "foo",
    members: [
        {
            key: "bar",
            optional: false,
            definition: "string"
        },
        {
            key: "baz",
            optional: true,
            definition: "number"
        },
        {
            key: "bar",
            optional: true,
            definition: "eNum"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is this possible or does `TypeScript` not support that degree of reflection on `type` constructs?

Comment: It is partially doable in type scope. See [this](https://tsplay.dev/wOGxMw)

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine any chance of getting this in a jsfiddle set to typescript to view the output that is possible?  not allowing the name would be trivial for my application so if it can get the member definitions and optional attributes that's a huge leap forward for my use case, but it throws all kinds of errors when dropped into jsfiddle.

Comment: What do you mean: "to view the output". @Ben Wainwright is right, types are erased during the compilation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, native TypeScript does not contain such feature. But You can use [tst-reflect](https://github.com/Hookyns/tst-reflect) for example.

```js
import { getType, Property, Type } from 'tst-reflect';

export enum eNum {
  FOO = 0,
  BAR = 1,
}

export type foo = {
  bar: string;
  baz?: number;
  qux?: eNum;
};

const fooType: Type = getType<foo>();

console.log({
  name: fooType.name,
  members: fooType.getProperties().map(mapProperty),
});

function mapProperty(prop: Property) {
  return {
    key: prop.name,
    definition: prop.type.name,
    optional: prop.optional,
  };
}
```

Output:

```
{
  name: 'foo',
  members: [
    { key: 'bar', definition: 'String', optional: false },
    { key: 'baz', definition: 'Number', optional: true },
    { key: 'qux', definition: 'eNum', optional: true }
  ]
}
```

Working example here: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/tst-reflect-example-stackoverflow-72682272?file=index.ts).

Answer (score 2):

Types do not exist at runtime, so this is not possible.

Comment: Are there any good `TypeScript` AST generators like `esprima` is for `JavaScript`?  This is being run via node.js so something like parseType(__filename, name) is probably the way I'm going to have to implement it - the `TypeScript` team was pretty against adding reflection when asked.